# Google Sheets - Query where column is equal to a range of cells

Tags: google-sheets

I'm putting together a list of invoices based on Project Names. Essentially, I have the following lists

| Project List |
| --- |
| Client A - Project |
| Client B - Project |

| Invoice List | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Client A - Project | 6,000 |
| Client A - Project | 5,000 |
| Client C - Project | 2,000 |

I want to write a query that will pull from the Invoice list according to what's on the project list.

The formula I have is giving me an empty output.

```
  =query(Invoices!A:B,"select * where A matches '"& TEXTJOIN("|",1,Projects!A2:A10) &"'",0)
```

My only thought is that the actual sheet has square brackets around the Client names and somehow that is breaking the query. I couldn't add them here without the website thinking I had code.

Comment: `the actual sheet has square brackets around the Client names` then put sample data with square bracket. `FILTER()` with `COUNTIFS()` using wild card may help.

Comment: I tried, but StackOverflow wouldn't let me submit my question with them

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
=filter(Invoices!A:B,xmatch(Invoices!A:A,Projects!A2:A10))
```